# Regular expression to check if an input has characters or at least 1 smiley face?

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I need a regular expression to validate if an input text box has at least 1 smiley face (GOOD: ':), =), etc.' BAD: ':, (, etc.') and that also accepts any character from the alphabet.

I have this one: [0-9A-Za-z'\&-./()=:;]+ but it also accepts me for example this -> ':'

I need this to use it in a javascript function.

What's the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You may need to define all your smiley faces in the regular expression

Comment: To clarify, you're looking for a regex that allows non-alphanumeric symbols *only* when they are part of a smiley? And you *also* want to validate that at least one smiley exists? Or do you *only* want to validate the existence of at least smiley?

Comment: Just to validate the existence of at least one smiley face

Comment: What about Unicode emojis ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to check for any smiley in your text:

```
/\:\)|\=\)|\:,/
```

Comment: Your regex expression finds any of these special characters, but these characters are not making smiley separately. Smiley is made by some of fixed combinations of these characters.

Comment: @WaqasShabbir It isn't. Please note the `|` operator. Also `/\:\)|\=\)|\:,/.test(':')` will return `false` but `/\:\)|\=\)|\:,/.test(':)')` will return `true`.